# How to make Highlight for search results by Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

in view:

```
@if($posts)
            @foreach($posts as$post)
                <h2>
                    <a href="{{route('home.post',$post->id)}}">{{$post->title}}</a>
                </h2>
                <p class="lead">
                    by <a href="index.php">{{$post->user->name}}</a>
                </p>
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted {{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</p>
                <hr>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{$post->photo->file}}" alt="">
                <hr>
                {!! str_limit($post->body,35 )!!}
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('home.post',$post->id)}}">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                <hr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

in controller:

```
public function searchmulti(){
        $keyword=Input::get('title');
        $posts = Post::where('title', 'like', "%$keyword%")->get();
        return view('Admin.comments.postsauthor',compact('posts'));
       }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert search result to array with `toArray()` method ([see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-serialization)) and then
iterate through results and use `str_replace` to replace searched word with `<span class="highlight">your word</span>`

after this you will have `$post['title']` (instead of `$post->title`) with highlighted span inside

of course you must add `.highlight` with some styling in your css

```
$posts = Post::where('title', 'like', "%$keyword%")->get()->toArray();
foreach($posts as &$post){
  $post['title']=str_replace($keyword,"<span class='highlight'>$keyword</span>",$post['title']);
}
```

PS if you don't want to convert results to array you can edit tile in eloquent model directly but I prefer arrays to be certain that I don't save changes accidently

Comment: please,can you show me this by code? thanks in advance

Comment: I've added some code in edit, but this code is not tested - just from memory

Comment: I tried this and show this error:  Trying to get property of non-object  in view

Comment: because you are still using post as object instead of array i think. use `$post['title']` instead of arrows in your view for all post properties like `$post['id']` instead of `$post->id` and so on...

Comment: I did all this but show the same error **Trying to get property of non-object in view**